# Unable to use HP LaserJet 1010 as network printer after upgrade to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, printing

Since I upgraded all three computers to Ubuntu 12.04, I am unable to use my HP LaserJet-1010 as a network printer. It works fine as local printer. The network works, too (At least I am able to ping between the computers). I am user in the lp and lpadmin groups. Before the upgrade it all worked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trouble shoot guide available ,try that one

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu#Troubleshooting